# What's a good method for summarizing point data in arcgis when trying to create a fraction between three feature layers

Tags: arcgis

I'm trying to understand how point data from two gps devices varies from our baseline data. I have three feature layers in ArcGIS.

1. gps #1 data(point)
2. gps #2 data(point)
3. baseline records of expected point data(point)

I'd like to make comparisons of the two gps devices by understanding the proportion of each gps data within each census tracts and symbolize by the proportion covered.

What would be the most efficient way to calculate this? Could I build this out in Model Builder to analyze at various levels of geography?